# StreamTokenizer to Hashmap in Java Output Errors

Tags: java, hashmap, token, cpu-word

I am attempting to store every word as a token into a hashmap. However, sometimes it stores every word, sometimes it stores a few words in a row and sometimes it does not even store the characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        File file = new File("jarg2912.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StreamTokenizer sT = new StreamTokenizer(bufferedReader);
        sT.eolIsSignificant(true);
        sT.whitespaceChars(' ', 0);
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        while(sT.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            if (sT.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
                hashMap.put(String.valueOf(sT.nval), sT);
            } else {
                hashMap.put(sT.sval, sT);
            }
        }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println("Index:");
        for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Current Output:

```
Plea
s own typed input.  Compare
Member
s bitmapped terminal the words "THE BAG" in
tenure
versa
readable
 as a qualifier.  "When is the system coming up?"
natures
indirect
Sun.
goes
behaviors
t.  The result is gossipy, funny,
datagram
idiosyncrasies
posed
reader.
general.
s last {{ITS}} machines, the one on the upper
obtusity
chances
crosstalk
rods
herself
potentially
but....
annoyance.
database-theory
Haven
covering
instances
Generic
prosyletic
Editing
computer-science
weakly
tune
cam
stampe
iterating.
aware
can
numerical
eXchange
aficionados.
award
stoppage
TM-postfix
23.0
mega-
car
floating
cat
.  Reports from {old fart}s are consistent that
flew
alarm
behavior.
stamps
depersonalization
carried
cleaning
Fnord.
Suns
Morse-code
motion
closed.
BAD
 has been adopted, retaining the DDT abbreviation.
s surroundings again
998.0
heavy-metal
apostrophes
distracted
Dick
poseurs
clothes
fragment
carrier
BAR
carries
response
independently
TENEX.
```

I need to be able to store each and every symbol, number and word as a token, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Part of file:

## ========= THIS IS THE JARGON FILE, VERSION 2.9.12, 10 MAY 1993 =========

x
This is the Jargon File, a comprehensive compendium of hacker slang
illuminating many aspects of hackish tradition, folklore, and humor.

This document (the Jargon File) is in the public domain, to be freely
used, shared, and modified.  There are (by intention) no legal
restraints on what you can do with it, but there are traditions about
its proper use to which many hackers are quite strongly attached.
Please extend the courtesy of proper citation when you quote the File,
ideally with a version number, as it will change and grow over time.
(Examples of appropriate citation form: "Jargon File 2.9.12" or
"The on-line hacker Jargon File, version 2.9.12, 10 MAY 1993".)

The Jargon File is a common heritage of the hacker culture.
Over the years a number of individuals have volunteered considerable
time to maintaining the File and been recognized by the net at large
as editors of it.  Editorial responsibilities include: to collate
contributions and suggestions from others; to seek out corroborating
information; to cross-reference related entries; to keep the file in a
consistent format; and to announce and distribute updated versions
periodically.  Current volunteer editors include:

Comment: Can you share your text file? The reason might be it contains white-space characters other than ' '.

Answer (score 0):

Change `sT.whitespaceChars(' ', 0)` to `sT.whitespaceChars(0, ' ')` and change `sT.eolIsSignificant(true)` to `sT.eolIsSignificant(false)`.

Also, you should be using a HashSet, not a HashMap.